# How to display custom comment fields onto any page

Tags: comments

In the latest version of WordPress, if I added the following code to include a custom field to my functions.php file...

```php
function add_comment_fields($fields) {
    $fields['source'] = '<p class="comment-form-source ast-col-xs-12 ast-col-sm-12 ast-col-md-4 ast-col-lg-4"><label for="source" class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Related Publishing Source' ) . '</label>' .
        '<input id="source" name="source" type="text" value="" placeholder="Publishing Source" size="30" aria-required="true" /></p>';
    return $fields;
}
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','add_comment_fields');
```

...how do I "display the results" of this custom field onto the comments page for each comment posted?

I was looking at the [get_comments function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments/), with an example like so....

```php
<?php
$args = array(
    'user_id' => 1, // use user_id
);
$comments = get_comments( $args );
 
foreach ( $comments as $comment ) :
    echo $comment->comment_author . '<br />' . $comment->comment_content;
endforeach;
```

But that relates to the OOTB comments provided my wordpress.  How can we display our new custom fields in this same fashion?

I found [this article](https://www.pmg.com/blog/adding-extra-fields-to-wordpress-comments/) from 2011 on what I am trying to achieve.  WordPress has changed dramatically sense then. Is there a 2020 version of that article for WordPress 5+ ...?

Many thanks!

Comment: did you look into get_comment_meta()  - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_meta/

Comment: Did you debug the return value from the function? to a log for example?

Comment: That sounds cool, but I have very little experience with using that.  I placed `?><pre><?php var_dump(  $fields['source']  ); ?></pre><?php` at the bottom of my functions.php file, but the output on my browser window says its null.

Comment: Can you try:   echo get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'source', true );

Comment: Can you check phpmyadmin and look in the comment_meta table for comment meta data matching the comment ID with "source" value?

Comment: I'm now realizing there are several more steps I need to make to achieve my goal   I updated my post to show where I am getting at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case others are stumped with trying to learn how to reveal submitted comments onto a comments page (or any page for this matter), a good starting point to investigate is using the WordPress function [wp_list_comments()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_comments/)

There are examples provided on that resource page to get things going in a healthy direction.

I would also include the following debug tactic as a help along the way...

```php
?><pre><?php var_dump( $variable_to_test ); ?></pre><?php
```

...as mentioned by [Q Studio](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/7968/q-studio).  Thanks for that!

**Update**

[Another good resource](https://wpengineer.com/2214/adding-input-fields-to-the-comment-form/) to help extend the OOTB comment fields with more fields by WPengineer.com.  I've tested it out for myself in 2020, and concepts still work.